# Are there templates for Angular 2 templates?

Tags: templates, angular, generics, inheritance, angular2-template

Facelets, Thymeleaf, ASP.NET and other view frameworks supports templating to create uniform GUI. Are there templates for Angular 2 templates? E.g. I would like to have business form template with commond comands such as Save, Cancel, Exit and use this template for all my business forms? I am not sure that repearing Save/Cancel/Exit commands in the code of eache page is good idea. Angular 2 components allow inheritance and genercis and maybe template code allow something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on [Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) and [Angular Material 2](https://github.com/angular/material2)